# Exception handling in GUI: Unable to show message dialog

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, applet

When I was writing the code below, I intend to input double values from keyboard. If the input is not a double value, a dialog window will pop to force input again.

```
boolean continueLoop=true;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            String firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first floating-point value" );
            number1 = Double.parseDouble( firstNumber );
            continueLoop=false;
        }
        catch ( InputMismatchException inputMismatchException )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please type in a valid, real number","Input Error",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }while ( continueLoop );
```

However the dialog window never shows when I input invalid numbers. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch `NumberFormatException`, look at the [Double#parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

`InputMismatchException` is thrown when you are trying to read a specific type with another `nextxxxx()` function of a `Scanner`. But `Double.parseDouble(String)` will throw `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable `double`, which you will need to catch.